# Mysql order by using search string

Tags: mysql, string, sql-like, sql-order-by

i have a mysql query like:

```
select * from employee 
  where name like '%ani%'
```

I want my results to be order by starting with ani
for eg. my results should be comming as:
{anil,anirudha,rani, ...} starting with ani first and then followed by other characters.

Can anybody please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
select * from employee where name like '%ani%' order by locate('ani', name) asc, name asc
```

Should do the trick ... (sort by position of the substring in the whole string)

Comment: it will work for string starting with ani .. but if string starts with info then it wont work

Comment: Well, the location will return 0, 1, 2 ... for strings starting with 'ani', '.ani', '..ani' ... I see a pattern there ... 'infoani' should return 4 ?

Comment: Aha, replace 'ani' with the strign of your choice, e.g. 'info', 'whatever', etc ...

Comment: @EzekielRage i like you solution. although seems that mysql like function and locate function are not working the same on some characters. for example searching  ā with like will be found(using `utf8_general_ci` or `utf_unicode_ci`) but it wont be find by locate. see my post http://stackoverflow.com/q/21695687/1211174 **EDIT 3** is relevent for that. any ideas how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use a union to achieve this:

```
select * from employee where name like 'ani%' order by name
union 
select * from employee where name like '%ani%' and not name like 'ani%' order by name
```

Comment: What if the searched string is `zanzibar` and you have three strings containing this word: `zanzibar`, `zanzibar tanzania` and `alamo zanzibar` ?  Your query will have this results: `alamo zanzibar`, `zanzibar` and `zanzibar tanzania` which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure exactly what you are looking for. If you would like to just order the results of that query by name:

```
select * from employee 
  where name like '%ani%'
order by name asc;
```

Comment: i am lokking for sorting my results base on query string for eg for a query like select * from employee where name like '%info%' .... results should be sorted as infosys,infobridge,shell info ...

Comment: The results of this query will be sorted by employee name and will exclude employees that do not contain %ani%. I am slightly confused by the ordering in your comment. Does the name need to be sorted by ascending or descending? I was thinking infobridge would come before infosys

Answer (score 0):

```
select  * from employee 
where name like '%'+'ani'+'%'
order by if(SUBSTRING(name, 1, length('ani'))= 'ani', 0,1), name
```

for mssql server repalce `if` with `case when`
with the syntax provided, is easy to replace 'ani' with any value you want